# How to serialize and deserialize an interface using IXmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlwriter

I'm trying to serialize an interface. I know that this is impossible throught the standart serialization, that's the reason why I used the custom serialization in a base class.

```
public interface IFoo 
{ 
    object Value { get; } 
} 

public abstract class Foo<T> : IFoo, IXmlSerializable 
{ 
    [XmlElement] 
    public T Value { get; set; } 
    [XmlIgnore] 
    object IFoo.Value { get { return Value; } } 

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema() { return null; } 
    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader) { throw new NotImplementedException(); } 
    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) 
    { 
        XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(Value.GetType()); 
        serial.Serialize(writer, Value); 
    } 
} 

public class FooA : Foo<string> { } 
public class FooB : Foo<int> { } 
public class FooC : Foo<List<Double>> { } 
public class FooContainer : List<IFoo>, IXmlSerializable 
{ 
    public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; } 
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }  
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) 
    { 
        ForEach(x =>  
            { 
                XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(x.GetType()); 
                serial.Serialize(writer, x); 
            }); 
    } 
} 

class Program 
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        FooContainer fooList = new FooContainer() 
        { 
            new FooA() { Value = "String" }, 
            new FooB() { Value = 2 }, 
            new FooC() { Value = new List<double>() {2, 3.4 } }  
        }; 

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(fooList.GetType(), 
            new Type[] { typeof(FooA), typeof(FooB), typeof(FooC) }); 
        System.IO.TextWriter textWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\demo.xml"); 
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, fooList); 
        textWriter.Close(); 
    } 
}
```

My custom serializations are not correct. By the moment is saving for all the property Value, but to deserialized I really have no idea how to do this.

The idea is to save the property Value and to recover the fooContainer with the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A deserializer would not only deserialize the property values, but also the object containing them. That object cannot be of type `IMyInterface` as it is an interface and cannot be instantiated. You'll want to serialize an implementation of that interface, and deserialize it, or assign a default implementation of the interface to deserialize into.

Comment: Can you help posting the example? I haven't accomplished yet.